# Refreshing ViewModel's Entity Framework context

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, unit-testing, mvvm

I'm using WPF, MVVM and Entity Framework in my current project.

To keep things simple, let's say I have a viewmodel for CRUD operations towards a list of materials (Solid woods).

My ViewModel's EF context (*WTContext*) is initialized through property injection, for instance:

```
SolidWoods_VM newView = new SolidWoods_VM();
newView.Context = new WTContext(SettingsManager.Instance.GetConnectionString());
```

This way I'm able to test this ViewModel:

```
SolidWoods_VM swVM = new SolidWoods_VM();
swVM.Context = new FakeWTContext();
```

Imagine that during a insert operation something goes wrong and the WTContext.SaveChanges() fails.
What is the best way to refresh the ViewModels context?

1. Create a new bool property in the viewmodel named **ForTestingPurposes**, and when the SaveChanges method fails:

   ```
   try
   {
       Context.SaveChanges();
   }
   catch
   {
       if (!ForTestingPurposes)
       {
           Context = new WTContext(SettingsManager.Instance.GetConnectionString());
       }
   }
   ```
2. Send a message to the mainviewmodel for context reloading (through mediator pattern):

   ```
   Mediator.Instance.NotifyColleagues<SolidWoods_VM>(MediatorMessages.NeedToUpdateMyContext, this);
   ```

(Yet, this way I'd still need the bool property)

3.A more elegant solution, without aditional properties, provided for you guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not abstract the methods/properties you need on your data context onto an interface and then have an implementation of that that handles the exception.

```
//WARNING: written in SO window
public interface IDataSource
{
    void SaveChanges();
    //... and anything else you need ...
}

public class RealDataSource : IDataSource
{
    private WTContext _context;

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        try { _context.SaveChanges(); }
        catch
        {
            _context = new WTContext(/*...*/);
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can still implement a fake/mock data source but your view model class doesn't need to know anything about how the data is actually retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that your best bet would be the message.

You need a way to indicate that the save went wrong, and it might not serve all consumers of the class to have the context regenerated. If you're binding to your VM in there, for example, resetting the context might have other UI consequences.

Comment: While I was reading your answer I realized that even with the message option I need to have the bool property... I'm looking for an option where I don't need to declare properties specific for testing.